# Text message not being sent to a list of numbers but is sent when just one number is specified

Tags: java, android, arraylist, smsmanager

I am trying to build an application where the user can send his/her `location` to the stored phone numbers in a `sqlitedatabase`. I tested the application where the user can send the `location` as a text message to just one phone number and it worked but now when I try to create a `list` of numbers and pass it as a parameter in `sendTextMessage` method of `smsManager` the `location` as a text message is not sent. I have tried out the given code below so far,

**Code**

```
public class Gps4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlacesAPIActivity";
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
    private TextView display;
    private Button location_button,contacts_button;
    //String number="xxxxxxxxxx";
    ArrayList<String> numbers;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps4);
        numbers=new ArrayList<>();
        db = new UserDatabase(this).getReadableDatabase();
        location_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show_button);
        contacts_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view_button);
        display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location_textview);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Gps4Activity.this)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .build();

        location_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Gps4Activity.this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Gps4Activity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Gps4Activity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
                    }
                }
                callPlaceDetectionApi();
            }
        });

        contacts_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Gps4Activity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getContacts(){

        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+UserDatabase.TABLE_NAME,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String contact=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDatabase.NUMBER));
            numbers.add(contact);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    callPlaceDetectionApi();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                    "likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                    display.setText(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString());
                    messageSending(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString());
                    break;
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();

            }
        });
    }

    public void messageSending(String message){
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
//        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
        getContacts();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(numbers),null,message,null,null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent."+String.valueOf(numbers),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The commented lines are the ones when I tried to test the application with just one phone number. Also, suppose initially there is just one phone number in `sqlitedatabase` , as many times I click the `location_button` that many times the `arraylist` grows it's size. For example , initially if the `arraylist` has elements `[xxxxxx]` next time I click the `location_button` the `arraylist` will now have `[xxxxxx,xxxxxx]`.

Can anyone help me solving this issue?

Comment: `SmsManager` methods only handle one number at a time. You'll have to send them one by one.

Comment: Isn't there a way to send sms to multiple numbers at the same time

Comment: You can send them with loop ?

Comment: Oh!! yes. I could have done that. My bad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `sendTextMessage()` method only can take one number at a time, you need to execute this method for each number in the list.

That being said you should 'loop' through that `List`. Like this:

```
for (String number : numbers) {
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, message, null, null);
}
```

What it basically is saying is:

"Allright, let's take number one, sendTextMessage to number one, and I will keep doing this until I am done."

Comment: Thnaks for the help